# Trigger calling a store procecure is updating every data on table, instead of only one

Tags: mysql, sql

So, i have this two tables, **table_a** which have 2 triggers for insert and update the fields at another table ( table_b).

The main problem is, the delete and insert triggers works perfectly, but the update trigger, when used, instead of updating only the field with the same uid on the table_b, it is updating every field ( 20k + fields). I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, because when i run the sp code alone ( update query) it works as espected. but it just doesn't work when inside the stored procedure. Bellow, i'm setting

**trigger code:**

```
 CREATE definer=`test_user`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_update` after
  UPDATE
  ON `table_a` FOR EACH row CALL sp_update(old.uid,new.name, new.number)
```

**Stored procedure code:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_update`(IN `uid` CHAR(50), IN `name` CHAR(50), IN `number` CHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SET @UID = uid;
    SET @NAME= name;
    SET @NUMBER= number;
UPDATE tbl_master
SET
    name = @NAME,
    number = @NUMBER
where
  uid = @UID;
END
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For those who want to test it out, a test table with every trigger and sp involved in the process:

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
    `a` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
    `a` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Triggers**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `table_a` FOR EACH ROW CALL sp_insert(new.a, new.b, new.c);

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_a` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
call sp_update(old.a,new.b,new.c);
END;
```

**Procedures**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_insert`(IN `a` INT, IN `b` INT, IN `c` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
SET @A  =a;
SET @B = b;
SET @C = c;
insert into table_b (a,b,c) values (@A, @B, @C);
end

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_update`(IN `a` INT, IN `b` INT, IN `c` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
set @A = a;
set @B = b;
set @C = c;
update table_b set b=@B, c=@c where a=@A;
END
```

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm using really small values for this test table that i pasted the code . like 1,2,3. and still, i'm getting the same behaviour.

Comment: @RyanVincent it seems that  the trigger isn't passing the old.a value.

Comment: @RyanVincent I forgot to mention, that our client is running mysql 5.2, maybe that behavior don't happen on recent versions :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i managed to find out what was causing this issue. I'm not sure if it is relevant or not, but since the MySQL Server is running on a windows server, I'm not sure if this issue is related to the OS or it's a behavior of the database itself.

Basicaly, it seend that i cannot use the same variable name ( inputs are in lower case, and routine body vars are in upper case). So , i had to change it from:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_update`(IN `a` INT, IN `b` INT, IN `c` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
set @A = a;
set @B = b;
set @C = c;
update table_b set b=@B, c=@c where a=@A;
END
```

To:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_update`(IN `v_a` INT, IN `v_b` INT, IN `v_c` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
set @A = v_a;
set @B = v_b;
set @C = v_c;
update table_b set b=@B, c=@c where a=@A;
END
```

Not sure if it it's my fault for using the same variable names , or if it's mysql fault for not recognizing the difference between lower/upper case characters.